# Ghostscript removing trim and bleed boxes and output profiles

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We have ready created single page pdfs with trim and bleed boxes and greyscaled using an ICC profile. We are then using Ghostscript to combine into a multi-page pdf however after it has combined them the trim and bleed boxes disappear and the greyscale reverts to color. We can use the Ghostscript greyscale command but this doesn't help with the trim/bleed boxes which we need for imposition.

This is what we are using:

```
$command = 'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile="' . $outputPath . '" ' . implode(' ', $pdfFiles);
```

Be glad of any help or suggestions, we do a high volume so are currently using PDFTK to combine which keeps the boxes but doesn't fix the greyscale issue either.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated which operating system you are using, nor which version of Ghostscript, and you haven't supplied an example file.

The pdfwrite device goes to considerable effort **not** to alter the colour space or values of the input. If the input is in DeviceGray, then the output will be in DeviceGray, unless you specifically request a different space using the ColorConversionStrategy switch. What exactly do you mean by "the greyscale reverts to colour" ? The PDF displays differently ? Some other tool reports the file is 'colour' ?

There's really nothing anyone can suggest without a lot more information, in particular an example input file and ideally the file after you've run it through Ghostscript using the pdfwrite device.

Please note that Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not 'combine' PDF files. The actual process is complex, and though the end result may appear to be the original files 'combined' that's not what is going on behind the scenes. The actual process is documented [here.](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.26/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)